# Redirect to another page after some time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am building a quizz app, so i have to end the test after the time expired.

I store :

- initial time when the user joined
- final time when the user must end the session
  Both in milisecond

How could i know when the time is due so that i redirect the user?

Comment: Could use setInterval?

Comment: [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) should do what you need. How you trigger a redirect depends on what router you're using.

Comment: Set a condition, when finaltime is reached window.location.replace(...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to execute code after a certain period of time.

```
const second = 1000;
const minute = 60 * second;
const hour = 60 * minute;
```

```
const allowed_time = 2 * hour + 15 * minute;

setTimeout(function () {
  // redirect user
}, allowed_time);
```

Or in case you don't have a duration, but a concrete end time.

```
const allowed_time = Date.UTC(2021, 8, 9, 17, 30) - Date.now(); // 21-08-17 17:30
```

This answer assumes that you don't exceed the maximum delay value.

> #### [Maximum delay value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#maximum_delay_value)
>
> Browsers including Internet Explorer, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox
> store the delay as a 32-bit signed integer internally. This causes an
> integer overflow when using delays larger than 2,147,483,647 ms (about
> 24.8 days), resulting in the timeout being executed immediately.

Comment: Sorry to ask but i never used setTimeout before, the setTimeOut should be placed in the constructor of the class?

Comment: @MasterWilliams Yes, `setTimeout()` is a global function and can be called from anywhere, so also from a constructor. Note that if you want to refer to `this` in the callback in the context of the constructor, you have to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of a normal function. [Arrow functions don't have their own `this` binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#arrow_functions) so it would then refer to the object you are currently constructing.